# Is it possible to use Python to detect the address of a (parallel) port?

Tags: python

I have an EEG experiment programmed in Python (PsychoPy, to be exact), and we send event markers to the EEG recording computer through one of [these adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001Q7X0W6). This requires giving Python the address of the adapter. Problem is, the address sometimes changes (I think when I reboot). Is it possible to have Python just automatically detect the port address? Or is that too low level for Python?

Comment: Do you have the code to perform what you wish in C or C++?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. I don't know C or C++. But are you suggesting that it might be possible to call such code from within Python?

Comment: This seems like a pretty low level bit of code, its likely that existing solutions are written in C/C++. cython is quite nice at talking between python and c or c++. http://cython.org/

Comment: Do you have a target OS in mind?  This sort of thing would differ at least on a linux\unix vs windows perspective I'd think.

Comment: It'll be on a Windows machine.